# update database from foreach loop php not working

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello am trying to update a column in my sql database using values from a foreach loop but am getting..Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
        foreach($ids as $id){
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://api.twitter.com/1/
    users/lookup.json?user_id=".$id."");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // grab URL and pass it to the browser
    $contents = curl_exec ($ch);
    $ok=array();
    $ok=json_decode($contents,true);
    foreach($ok['results'] as $p){
        $location=$p['location'];
        $query=mysql_query("UPDATE tweets SET location=".$location."
         WHERE from_user_id=".$id."");
        if($query){
            print'ok';
        }else{print'sds';}
    }
    // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

cheers people!!!!

Comment: Comment out the `foreach` and do a `print_r($ok['results']);` I don't think that it is a valid array.

Comment: am not getting anything (empty page)

Comment: Then there is an error. Comment out the _entire_ `foreach()` loop and put the `print_r($ok['results']);` directly the `json_decode()`

Comment: Then obviously your JSON is not returning a proper array.

Comment: the problem is with the curl thing because am echoing out the page and I get 1111111

Comment: Then you may want to read-up on how to use curl!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need. It only pulls the last tweet but it is a good start. Your call to twitter api is no longer working, put it in a browser window and you will find that it errors.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://api.twitter.com/users/".$id.".json");
$ok=json_decode($contents,true);

# For Testing Purposes
#echo '<pre>';
#var_dump($ok);
#echo '</pre>';

echo $ok['location'];
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP arrays, whether associative or not, have a key and a value for each pair.

So, it should be `foreach($ids as $id_number => $id) {` as I'm guessing, since you didn't provide more information on the `$ids` array.

Comment: yes there was a problem with the first array but now i want to loop and get the location from this array.

Comment: from your other comments, $ok['results'] is not a valid php array